# Backbone 'change:attribute' sometimes doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

As I understand in 'change' event Backbone is checking if the set value is the same as the previous one.

Do yo know some possibilities to overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you invoke the set methods yourself you can wrap your Model set function in a another function that will fire an event, like this:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    mySet: function (value) {        
        var result = this.set(value);
        this.trigger('myChange', value);

        return result;
    }
});

var item = new Item();
item.on('myChange', function (value) {
    alert('My change event fired');
});
```